# How to implement an Asynchronous for loop for a windows store javascript app?

Tags: javascript, loops, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps

Am currently working on a windows store javascript application and stuck at implementing the asynchronous for loop.

Consider a simple for loop as follows

```
for(i=0,i<4,i++)
{
//body
}
```

What will be the exact asyncFor loop that can execute the same process as the above code

Comment: Is there any difference between a windows-store-app and usual JS in regards to asynchronity?

Answer (score 0):

Use callback functions.

```
someFunction = function(data, ...){
    someAsyncFn(someFunction); //use this function as the callback
}
```

Comment: Will this ever come to an end?

Answer (score 0):

Only if I understood you correct... You coud try something like this:

```
function asyncFor(n, callback)
{
    var i=0;
    var t=setInterval(function(){
        callback();
        i++;
        if(i==n)
            clearInterval(t);
    }, 0);
}

asyncFor(4, function(){
    console.log('hello world');
});
console.log('after for');
```

If not - sorry and ignore my answer

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you need to code the loop recursively - invoking the next recursion step from the asynchronous callback:

```
function loop(i, n, body, callback) {
    if (i < n)
        body(i, function cb() {
            loop(i+1, n, body, callback);
        });
    else
        callback();
}
```

Then use it like

```
loop(0, 4, function(i, cb) {
    console.log(i);
    setTimeout(cb, 50); // or whatever async task with callback you have
}, function() {
    console.log("done everything");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use a recursive function callback
 function test(){
  myCall(function(){
       alert("Hello world");
    },5);
 }
function myCall(callback , count){
      if(count === 0){
           return;
      }else{
         callback();
         count--;
      }
      myCall(callback , count);
}
```

Comment: I don't see any asynchronity in here. Isn't this just equivalent to `for (var count=5; count>0; count--) alert("Hello world");`?

Comment: Yeah, I got confused with the question, I think you need a multithread scenario but javascript is not, so you can use a library for this like this -> http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/jsthread/index.php?title=Main_Page.

Comment: You don't need any threads for asynchronous programming. And all these "threading libs" are actually code converters that transform custom keywords and coding into actual JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looping over an array, these two helpers may come in handy (CoffeeScript syntax for more succinct notation). Feel free to convert them to standalone functions if you're uncomfortable with monkey-patching.

```
# call function for each element in array
# returns when all promises have been completed
Array::eachAsync = (fn) ->
  promises = @map (item, index, collection) -> fn(item, index, collection)
  WinJS.Promise.join(promises)

# call function for each element in array in order
# returns when the last one has been processed
Array::sequentialEachAsync = (fn) ->
  @reduce (lastPromise, item) ->
    lastPromise.then () -> fn(item)
  , WinJS.Promise.wrap()
```